# MySQL full Unicode support issue : Variable 'innodb_file_format' is a read only variable ( MOODLE 3.10.1 Installation)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, moodle

I want to install MOODLE 3.10.1 in the local server (xampp windows 10 pc) for my own learning. According to the installation guide I need to Compile the following

"Your database uses Antelope as the file format. Full UTF-8 support in MySQL and MariaDB requires the Barracuda file format. Please switch to the Barracuda file format. See the documentation MySQL full Unicode support for details."

According to the moodle installation guide (https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support), I ran the following SQL command and I am getting the following error.

> #1238 - Variable 'innodb_file_format' is a read only variable

Other details of PHP MYADMIN

- PHP Version 7.3.26
- System Windows NT DESKTOP-LTTS1D7 10.0 build 18363    Windows 10) AMD64
- Build Date   Jan 5 2021 15:04:15
- Compiler MSVC15(Visual C++ 2017)

[image: Moodle installtion guide picture]
[image: Screen shot of error code appearing]
[image: XAMPP server image]

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it does not work. In PHP 7.1 version this problem doesn't occur but moodle installation required  PHP 7.2 or above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'innodb_file_format' must be set by editing the 'my.ini' file. It can not be changed in phpmyadmin.

Comment: What version of MySQL (or MariaDB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be mitigated if selected the marriandb instead of mysqli. In the database created a table named **moodle** and with the formatting of **utf8mb4_general_ci**
In the above method no need to run the sql commands to UTF stands
[image]